# Strange output at after copy an array of char from a pointer to a line file

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to read and store the data at some file (I have another program that tells me how many rows and columns I have). Now I am trying store the data at the file using a bidimensional array, a pointer and fgets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i=0,b=0;
    char value[1024][3];
    char (*p)[3] = value;

    char line[1024];
    FILE *fp=fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("\nThe file does not exist\n");
    }
    else{
        while( fgets ( line, sizeof(line), fp ) != NULL  )
            {
                strcpy(p[i],line);
                printf ("%s",p[i]);
                printf("\n");
                i++;

             }
             printf ("%s",value[0]);
             printf("\n");

    }



    return 0;
}
```

From what I know ( and I know I am wrong… because I have an strange output ). p points to value and then I use strcpy to copy the content from line(1) to p(1) and value[lenght][1].

The output inside the while is ok p[0] prints the correct numbers, also p[1], and so on. When I try to print the value outside the loop (to verify) I get an strange output.

The file is ASCII and his content is ( no lines, they represent a tab):

1-2-3-44

2-33-4-5

22-3-5-12

The print at the while shows the next( no lines, they represent a tab):

1-2-3-44

2-33-4-5

22-3-5-12

The print outside shows the next:

1-22-322-3-5-12

Prints the first two numbers of the 1 row, the first two numbers of the second row and the complete third row. However if I change p[0] to p[2] prints the third row without errors:

22-3-5-12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want three rows of 1024 chars.

With this `char value[1024][3];` you have 1024 rows of 3 chars.

Switch the height and width of the array value and pointer p.